# Accessing the Callback function in ROS while inside a while loop?

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I'm programming a little robot, that needs to switch modes when pressing a button.
Basically, it should drive manually, and when you press the cross button on a ps controller it changes to the camera mode, where it follows a black line

However when using my current code, I can enter the automatic mode, but I can't use the buttons (they come from the joy package) I think it's because I'm locked in a while loop and it cant exist to check if a button is pressed.

Anyway here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 160)
cap.set(4,120)
button_pressed = [0]
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)

def callback(data):
    global button_pressed
    button_pressed=data.buttons
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + " Motor Links: %s ; Motor Rechts: %s ; Stepper: %s", round(data.axes[2],2), round(data.axes[5],2), round(data.axes[1],2))
#119 W
    
    automodus = 2
    if data.buttons[2]==1:
        automodus = 1
    if data.buttons[5]==1:
        automodus = 0
    if automodus == 0:
        coole_manuellsteuerung(data)
    if automodus == 1:
        autocamera(data)
        
def coole_manuellsteuerung(data):
    if data.axes[5] != 0:
            
            # Simplified: Driving when Stick isnt in neutral
            GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(23, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)       


def autocamera(data):
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        low_b = np.uint8([5,5,5])
        high_b = np.uint8([0,0,0])
        mask = cv2.inRange(frame, high_b, low_b)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, 1, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        if len(contours) > 0 :
            c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            if M["m00"] !=0 :
                cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
                cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
                print("CX : "+str(cx)+"  CY : "+str(cy))
                if cx >= 120 :
                    print("Turn Left")
                if cx < 120 and cx > 40 :
                    print("On Track!")
                if cx <=40 :
                    print("Turn Right")
                cv2.circle(frame, (cx,cy), 5, (255,255,255), -1)
        else :
            print("I don't see the line")
            # Stop Driving
        cv2.drawContours(frame, c, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
        cv2.imshow("Mask",mask)
        cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & button_pressed[5]:   # 1 is the time in ms
            # Stop Driving
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('Coole_Motorsteuerung', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("/joy", Joy, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
    rospy.loginfo(button_pressed)
```

The problem lies in the following part i think. I want to leave this mode when i press button[5] (the x button)

```
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & button_pressed[5]:   # 1 is the time in ms
            # Stop Driving
            break
```

Thanks for the help!
Sincerely Pascal

created a global variable "button_pressed" but it's not changing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to the fact that your camera processing does not give `rospy` a chance to process the incoming messages (more on this here: [ROS Answers: Difference between rospy.spin and rospy.sleep](https://answers.ros.org/question/332192/difference-between-rospyspin-and-rospysleep/)). Try this solution:

```py
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import cv2
import numpy as np

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)

class LineFollower():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap.set(3, 160)
        self.cap.set(4,120)
        # does not solve possible concurrency issues, but works
        self.enable_camera = False 
        self.buttons_pressed = [0]

    def callback(self, data):
        self.buttons_pressed=data.buttons

        # throws an exception for me
        rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + " Motor Links: %s ; Motor Rechts: %s ; Stepper: %s", round(data.axes[2],2), round(data.axes[5],2), round(data.axes[1],2))

        automodus = 2
        if self.buttons_pressed[2]==1:
            automodus = 1
        if self.buttons_pressed[5]==1:
            automodus = 0
        if automodus == 0:
            self.enable_camera = False
            self.coole_manuellsteuerung(data)
        if automodus == 1:
            self.enable_camera = True
            
    def coole_manuellsteuerung(self, data):
        if data.axes[5] != 0: # throws an exception for me
            print("GPIO")
            # # Simplified: Driving when Stick isnt in neutral
            GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(23, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)       

    def process_camera_data(self):
        if self.enable_camera:
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            low_b = np.uint8([5,5,5])
            high_b = np.uint8([0,0,0])
            mask = cv2.inRange(frame, high_b, low_b)
            contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, 1, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            if len(contours) > 0 :
                c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
                M = cv2.moments(c)
                if M["m00"] !=0 :
                    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
                    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
                    print("CX : "+str(cx)+"  CY : "+str(cy))
                    if cx >= 120 :
                        print("Turn Left")
                    if cx < 120 and cx > 40 :
                        print("On Track!")
                    if cx <=40 :
                        print("Turn Right")
                    cv2.circle(frame, (cx,cy), 5, (255,255,255), -1)
                
                # moved this line, since the if-clause was causing exceptions
                cv2.drawContours(frame, c, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
            else:
                print("I don't see the line")

            cv2.imshow("Mask",mask)
            cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) and self.buttons_pressed[5]: 
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def main_cycle(self):
        rospy.init_node('Coole_Motorsteuerung', anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber("/joy", Joy, self.callback)
        try:
            while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                rospy.sleep(rospy.Duration(nsecs=1000)) # give time to process inbound msgs
                self.process_camera_data()
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
            print("shutdown")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    robot = LineFollower()
    robot.main_cycle()
    rospy.loginfo(robot.buttons_pressed)
```

This solution definitely does not claim to be the best. My goal was to keep as much of the original code as possible.
It is important to understand that this code also does not solve possible race conditions which may occur due to the way the callbacks are processed in  `rospy` (in separate threads - [see this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/313272/is-rospython-subscriber-thread-safe/?answer=325289#post-id-325289)); however this should be sufficient for a simple line follower task.
Some lines from the original code threw exceptions in my machine, however, it could have been related to the fact that I have used [joystick emulator](https://github.com/aquahika/rqt_virtual_joystick).